# Identify slow solr queries

Tags: solr

There are some queries that run very slow on my setup. Is there an easy way to identify and collect them (maybe through logs, or the admin console), so that I can do some performance analysis later on?

Answer (score 3):

yes, very easy in the logs, look at a sample line

```
INFO: [core0] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params={indent=on&start=0&q=*:*&version=2.2&rows=10} hits=1074 status=0 QTime=1
```

You need to look at Qtime

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of the logs and the QTime. In my case though, I have a large load of queries (many thousands per day). I suppose I could write a filter to identify the more costly ones, but I was wondering if there is something similar available already in Solr.

Answer (score 2):

It is targeted for version 4.3 as of now. 
here is the issue link. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1101